# WinXP: connecting to AdHoc network

Tags: networking, adhoc-network

Using WinXP SP3. Trying to create an ad-hoc wireless network for ipod. (Also has a primary wired network).

Using a USB wireless adapter. (All drivers installed,etc).

When I configure the wireless device to connect to ad hoc I get an error:

"some configurations changes were not saved"

I check the group permissions (gpedit.msc) and I can't seem to find anywhere that this setting would be set.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you've got multiple devices you can use to attempt to the ad-hoc and none of them can connect successfully?  Or am I reading that wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I think there is some security policy somewhere but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of doing this.

1. Bridge your wired and wireless connections, your router will see your ipod just like it is on the wired network and assign it an IP and give it network access.
2. Setup internet connection sharing. in network properties right click on the network connection you want to share (in this case it would be your wired network) and select the check box that says "allow others to use this computers network connection to access the internet" And then select your wireless connection to share it with. Now when your ipod connects your computer will act as the router and provide it with internet access

Remember you will need admin rights on your computer to do this.

When connecting to the adhoc network have XP try to connect first, will it says "Waiting for network" when it first trys to connect have your ipod connect. once your ipod and your computer see each other they should connect.

If you want a dumbed down guide take a look at [This link](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/expert/bowman_02april08.mspx).